# How do I adjust the viewport size in SDL2.0 OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, sdl

I have no access to Glu functions with SDL2.0 SO i can't use GluPerspective() to define the rendering volume. Is there a Special function to handle this in SDL2.0? or a procedure?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the question is not clear enough, but the obvious answer to "how to adjust the viewport" in OpenGL is [glViewport](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml).

---

If you are looking for an alternative to GluPerspective, take a look into [glFrustum](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml). It is an OpenGL function, and should be available when glu functions are not.

Comment: I'm sorry, now that I review my question it seems pretty vague. My real problem is with SDL2.0. When I set up the OpenGL context and draw a pyramid the far clipping plane is cutting off the back of it. normally I would adjust this with the GluPerspective but Glu functions are not available in SDL2.0. at least I can't figure out how to use them if they are.

Comment: @JavainAlaska: You have a clear misunderstanding of what the *viewport* is. Your problem, is your current projection. The viewport is the area to which *already projected* (and normalized) vertices are mapped.

Comment: @thorka: thank you for clarifying, now if you can... answer the question.

Comment: @thorka: Sorry if that seemed a little snappy, I just woke up.

Comment: @BЈовић Hey, I like your answer but that was the first thing I tried. It seemed to have no effect whatsoever. I think the problem is actually with SDL2.0 windowing utility. there must be some function to adjust the rendering volume of the window it provides. I guess I will have to read the header files. You get a +1 anyway.